# Azure docker container gives 'Container use unauthorized'

Tags: azure, azure-container-service, azure-container-registry

I am trying to run Azure vision container with proper credentials, But when I perform the docker run command It gives me the following error for for Vision 3.0 and 3.1

```
Container is not in a valid state. Subscription validation failed with status 'ContainerUseUnauthorized'. The API Key provided is not authorized for use with this container. This is a gated container, make sure your Azure Subscription ID is approved: https://aka.ms/csgate. For more information please visit https://aka.ms/cscontainers-faq.
```

. When I use vision 2.0, I get this error

```
Billing endpoint connection failed with status 'Mismatch'. Api Key is not intended for the given container type.
```

I am sure that my Endpoint URL and key is valid.
I am using the following commands, can someone help?

```
docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/vision/read:3.1-preview Eula=accept Billing=************* ApiKey=************

docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/vision/read:2.0-preview Eula=accept Billing=************* ApiKey=************

docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/vision/read:3.0-preview Eula=accept Billing=************* ApiKey=************
```

Answer (score 0):

The API key provided is not authorized for use with this container. You are likely using a gated container, so make sure your Azure Subscription ID is approved by submitting an online [request](https://aka.ms/csgate).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/containers/container-faq